# Why does co-integration test give different results after swapping input series?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have two I(1) variables `cum_x` and `cum_y`:

```
>>> x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
>>> cum_x = np.cumsum(x)
>>> y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
>>> cum_y = np.cumsum(y)
```

If I put them to the co-integration test, and swap the order of the two variables, I get drastically different t-stat and p-values:

```
>>> import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts
>>> ts.coint(cum_x,cum_y)
(-2.3395054034978244, 0.35401442172951525, array([-4.01048603, -3.39854434, -3.08756793]))
>>> ts.coint(cum_y,cum_x)
(-1.6667470265609559, 0.69191381793176698, array([-4.01048603, -3.39854434, -3.08756793]))
```

Why is that? I'd expect whether two time series are co-integrated or not is a communicative property hence independent from the order of input variables?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might also be a good place to ask a general question about this if you don't get an answer here within a few days. Good question though.

Comment: The cointegrating equation is the same and it converges in large samples. The stochastic model, the location of the error term is different in the two versions, and in small samples the results can differ considerably. I don't have a reference right now, but there is the corresponding discussion in several articles, AFAIR.

Comment: Computationally, there could also be a difference if lag selection differs in the two versions. It's better to check that the underlying model that is used when computing the test statistic is the same.

Comment: One possible check, increase the sample size in the simulation to 10000 or so.

Comment: I tried to raise to even 100K data points but they still do not converge.